# How do I sync disks in a Windows guest before doing a snapshot?

Tags: windows, virtualization, snapshot

In general, before doing a disk snapshot of a virtual machine instance, the disk has to be synced to ensure that all buffers have been written to disk.

If the guest operating system is Linux, you can use a tool like fsfreeze for doing this. How do you ensure that the disk has been synced when the guest operating system is Windows-based?

*Edit*: I had OpenStack in mind when asking this question, so I'd be interested in answers for the following OpenStack-supported hypervisors:

- KVM
- Xen
- Hyper-V

Answer (score 5):

This depends entirely on what is taking the snapshot. VMware ESXi will use VMware Tools to quiesce the guest filesystem to make sure you have a consistent snapshot. Hyper-V does a similar operation when the enlightenment tools are installed.

I don't know of any virtualization solution that takes inconsistent snaps unless you explicitly tell it not to quiesce the guest filesystem. That's not to say that they don't exist, but without more details from you about what is actually doing the snapping, it's hard to say definitively.

Comment: I had OpenStack-supported hypervisors in mind (specifically: KVM, Xen, and Hyper-V). Edited the question accordingly. In particular, is there a way to do this with KVM?